# Match, group and get percent of documents by a specific date in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

### An exemple fo my data

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61cda8dabc3c3e648af34775"),
    "icone" : [ 
        "pomme", 
        "mangue"
    ],
    "is_good" : true,
    "date" : ISODate("2021-12-30T12:40:58.807Z")
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61cda8dabc3c3e648af34775"),
    "icone" : [ 
        "pomme", 
        "mangue"
    ],
    "is_good" : false,
    "date" : ISODate("2021-12-30T12:53:40.595Z")
}
```

Which query can I use to match by specific date and then group by date where "is_good" is true  ?

### The output that I'm expected is :

```json
[{

    "date" : ISODate("2021-12-30T12:53:40.595Z"),
    "is_good" : true,
    "count": 10,
    "percent" : 23%

},
{

    "date" : ISODate("2021-20-30T12:53:40.595Z"),
    "is_good" : true,
    "count": 10,
    "percent" : 12%

}]
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE You will have much better luck if you provide examples of what you've tried thus far, plus examples of what your output should look like.